# How i can change the /STACK:<stacksize> in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

i need to change the stack size in my project but i tried to open the option  the Property Pages in Visual Studio but did not appear that option to change the stack size.
Do you have any help how i can perform this operation?

Thanks so much .

Cheers

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tdkhxaks%28v=VS.100%29.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such setting in Visual studio. You will need to use the EDITBIN utility in a post-build command. Go to the property pages of your project and select build events. You can then paste something like this into the post-build textbox:

```
call "$(DevEnvDir)..\tools\vsvars32.bat"
editbin /STACK:<stacksize>"$(TargetPath)"
```